# Android - Automatically fill text fields of another app

Tags: android, textfield, autofill

I am implementing an Android app that is responsible for some data exchange with other services such as credentials. I then want to use that information to automatically fill in the input fields of other applications on the device such as Spotify.

Is there any way to fill the input fields of another app, like the username and password to remove the chore for the user to manually input it?

Also I noticed that at least on iOS, Spotify recognizes 1Password to be installed and displays a small icon next to the input fields with which I can fill the fields from the data stored in 1Password - how is this done as it seems to be another solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually this is the very topic of the last episode of [Android Developers Backstage](http://androidbackstage.blogspot.de/2018/03/episode-88-autofill.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to implement Autofill Service https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services.html

There is a ready to use sample app which will get you started https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AutofillFramework

Android will invoke `onFillRequest()` method giving your service a chance to show autofill suggestions. Here is a sample code from above link:

```
@Override
public void onFillRequest(FillRequest request, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, FillCallback callback) {
    // Get the structure from the request
    List<FillContext> context = request.getFillContexts();
    AssistStructure structure = context.get(context.size() - 1).getStructure();

    // Traverse the structure looking for nodes to fill out.
    ParsedStructure parsedStructure = parseStructure(structure);

    // Fetch user data that matches the fields.
    UserData userData = fetchUserData(parsedStructure);

    // Build the presentation of the datasets
    RemoteViews usernamePresentation = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    usernamePresentation.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, "my_username");
    RemoteViews passwordPresentation = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    passwordPresentation.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, "Password for my_username");

    // Add a dataset to the response
    FillResponse fillResponse = new FillResponse.Builder()
            .addDataset(new Dataset.Builder()
                    .setValue(parsedStructure.usernameId,
                            AutofillValue.forText(userData.username), usernamePresentation)
                    .setValue(parsedStructure.passwordId,
                            AutofillValue.forText(userData.password), passwordPresentation)
                    .build())
            .build();

    // If there are no errors, call onSuccess() and pass the response
    callback.onSuccess(fillResponse);
}

class ParsedStructure {
    AutofillId usernameId;
    AutofillId passwordId;
}

class UserData {
    String username;
    String password;
}
```

Comment: I'll have a look into it if I can solve my problem. Already thanks a lot

Comment: what is parseStructure and fetchUserData unable to resolve these

Comment: What is parseStructure method in this code ?

Comment: Is there any way that I can use this framework in react native?